# matplotlib from time series data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
example = {'year_month':  [201801,201802,201803,201801,201802,201803],
        'store_id': [101,101,101,102,102,102],
       'tot_employees': [100,200,150,6,7,10],
       'hrs_per_employee': [30,35,20,20,18,15]
        }
df = DataFrame(example,columns=["year_month", "store_id", "tot_employees", "hrs_per_employee"])
df
```

and i want to have stacked subplots with a different subplot for each store_id with:

- x axis: year_month
- plots line 1: tot employees
- plot line 2: hrs per
  employee

is this possible with df.plot()?  I haven't been able to find the correct x,y inputs to get the result i'm looking for. if not is there a close alternative?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(example)
df.year_month = pd.to_datetime(df.year_month, format='%Y%m', exact=True)
df.set_index('year_month', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
for x in df.store_id.unique():
    df[['tot_employees', 'hrs_per_employee']][df.store_id == x].plot(title=f'Store ID: {x}')
```

[image]

## Using only `df.groupby`

```
df.groupby('store_id').plot(y=['tot_employees', 'hrs_per_employee'])
```