# Multiple line plots from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have created a DataFrame () which looks at the variation in **x** number of ccy pairs (e.g: EURUSD and GBPEUR and so on...) from **y** number of different counterparties (e.g: X and Y and so on...) over a **n** month period (e.g: 3 month).

```
pairs   YearMonth   Counterparty    EURUSD     GBPUSD     ...    XXXZZZ
0       201905           X          0.002095  -0.023905   ...    ...
1       201905           Y          0.058331   0.040371   ...    ...
2       201906           X          0.098974   0.081692   ...    ...
3       201906           Y          0.781090   0.807301   ...    ...
4       201907           X          0.728668   0.120238   ...    ...
5       201907           Y          0.728668   0.120238   ...    ...
6       201908          ...          ...        ...       ...    ...
```

The aim is to create **x** different plots comparing the counterparties per ccy pair over the time period. (E.g: one for EURUSD, one for GBPUSD, and so on...)

I will have YearMonth on the x axis, the variation on the y axis.

I assume I will have to plot using some sort of for loop, but I cannot see anything online that suggests so? (note I work with R and thats how I would go about doing it there).

Many thanks for your ideas.

Comment: What do you mean with _"and both counterparties."_?

Comment: sorry that has no value ...

Comment: I suppose that you can profit from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57332040/2749397), it seems a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57331308/2749397) very similar to yours... (even if it not _exactly_ a duplicate).